# I want to convert pickle object to RDS object

Tags: python, r

I have a GBM pickle object i want to convert this pickle object into RDS object using reticulate package in R environment.

I have attempted to convert pickle to json and json to RDS
while converting pickle to json i am extracting parameters from pickle model object then saving in a dictionary and converting dict to json
now the main task is to convert json to RDS for that i am using rpy2 package but its throwing some class NoneType error

providing my code here ->

```
    import pickle
    import json
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
import numpy as np

def convert_to_serializable(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
        return obj.tolist()
    elif isinstance(obj, np.float32):
        return float(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, np.int32):
        return int(obj)
    else:
        return obj

# Load the pickle file containing the GradientBoostingRegressor object
with open('C:/Box/Prologis Revenue Management_TA/Working/Navin/pickle_ff.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

# Get parameters
learning_rate = model.learning_rate

# Get number of estimators
n_estimators = model.n_estimators

# Convert feature importances from ndarray to list
max_depth = model.max_depth

# Get training score
min_samples_leaf = model.min_samples_leaf

# Get validation fraction
subsample = model.subsample

loss = model.loss

verbose = model.verbose



# Create a dictionary with all the model information
model_info = {
    'learning_rate':learning_rate,
    'n_estimators': n_estimators,
    'max_depth': max_depth,
    'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
    'subsample': subsample,
    'loss': loss,
    'verbose':verbose
}

# Convert non-serializable objects to serializable format
model_info_serializable = {key: convert_to_serializable(value) for key, value in model_info.items()}

# Convert the dictionary to JSON format
json_data = json.dumps(model_info_serializable)

# Write the JSON data to a file
with open('C:/Box/Prologis Revenue Management_TA/Working/Navin/pkl_to_rds/model_info.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json_data)
```

json to rds conversion ->

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
# Load the jsonlite package in R
robjects.r("library(jsonlite)")

# Load the JSON data
with open("C:/Box/Prologis Revenue Management_TA/Working/Navin/pkl_to_rds/model_info.json", "r") as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)
    r_list = robjects.vectors.ListVector(gbm_model.get_params())
print(r_list)
```

but i am encountering this error

NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'NoneType'>'

please suggest me how to resolve this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.